# Install kivy python on 3.8.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I accidentally started installing in the PyCharm's terminal and in the command line at the same time
Don't look at the "base", without the base the same error.

When I tried to delete, I get the following message:

> WARNING: Skipping kivy as it is not installed.

When I try to install kivy,I get the following error :

```
  C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\github\kivy>pip install kivy[base]
    Collecting kivy[base]
      Using cached Kivy-1.11.1.tar.gz (23.6 MB)
      WARNING: Kivy 1.11.1 does not provide the extra 'base'
    Requirement already satisfied: Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4 in c:\users\michael\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from kivy[base]) (0.1.4)
    Requirement already satisfied: docutils in c:\users\michael\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from kivy[base]) (0.16)
    Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\michael\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from kivy[base]) (2.5.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\michael\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy[base]) (2.23.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\michael\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy[base]) (2.9)
    Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\michael\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy[base]) (1.25.8)
    Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\michael\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy[base]) (2019.11.28)
    Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\michael\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy[base]) (3.0.4)
    Building wheels for collected packages: kivy
      Building wheel for kivy (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477:
       command: 'c:\users\michael\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Michael\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7_3s7j11\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Michael\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7_3s7j11\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ohpcy0dl'
           cwd: C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7_3s7j11\kivy\
      Complete output (531 lines):
      Using setuptools
      User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
      Using this graphics system: OpenGL
      WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

      b'"pkg-config" \xad\xa5 \xef\xa2\xab\xef\xa5\xe2\xe1\xef \xa2\xad\xe3\xe2\xe0\xa5\xad\xad\xa5\xa9 \xa8\xab\xa8 \xa2\xad\xa5\xe8\xad\xa5\xa9\r\n\xaa\xae\xac\xa0\xad\xa4\xae\xa9, \xa8\xe1\xaf\xae\xab\xad\xef\xa5\xac\xae\xa9 \xaf\xe0\xae\xa3\xe0\xa0\xac\xac\xae\xa9 \xa8\xab\xa8 \xaf\xa0\xaa\xa5\xe2\xad\xeb\xac \xe4\xa0\xa9\xab\xae\xac.\r\n'

      WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

      b'"pkg-config" \xad\xa5 \xef\xa2\xab\xef\xa5\xe2\xe1\xef \xa2\xad\xe3\xe2\xe0\xa5\xad\xad\xa5\xa9 \xa8\xab\xa8 \xa2\xad\xa5\xe8\xad\xa5\xa9\r\n\xaa\xae\xac\xa0\xad\xa4\xae\xa9, \xa8\xe1\xaf\xae\xab\xad\xef\xa5\xac\xae\xa9 \xaf\xe0\xae\xa3\xe0\xa0\xac\xac\xae\xa9 \xa8\xab\xa8 \xaf\xa0\xaa\xa5\xe2\xad\xeb\xac \xe4\xa0\xa9\xab\xae\xac.\r\n'

      WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

      b'"pkg-config" \xad\xa5 \xef\xa2\xab\xef\xa5\xe2\xe1\xef \xa2\xad\xe3\xe2\xe0\xa5\xad\xad\xa5\xa9 \xa8\xab\xa8 \xa2\xad\xa5\xe8\xad\xa5\xa9\r\n\xaa\xae\xac\xa0\xad\xa4\xae\xa9, \xa8\xe1\xaf\xae\xab\xad\xef\xa5\xac\xae\xa9 \xaf\xe0\xae\xa3\xe0\xa0\xac\xac\xae\xa9 \xa8\xab\xa8 \xaf\xa0\xaa\xa5\xe2\xad\xeb\xac \xe4\xa0\xa9\xab\xae\xac.\r\n'

      ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
      fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\animation.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\app.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\atlas.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\cache.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\clock.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\config.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\context.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\event.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\factory.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\factory_registers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\geometry.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\gesture.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\interactive.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\loader.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\logger.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\metrics.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\multistroke.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\resources.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\support.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\utils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\vector.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\weakmethod.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      copying kivy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core
      copying kivy\core\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\audio
      copying kivy\core\audio\audio_avplayer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\audio
      copying kivy\core\audio\audio_ffpyplayer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\audio
      copying kivy\core\audio\audio_gstplayer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\audio
      copying kivy\core\audio\audio_pygame.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\audio
      copying kivy\core\audio\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\audio
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\camera
      copying kivy\core\camera\camera_android.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\camera
      copying kivy\core\camera\camera_gi.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\camera
      copying kivy\core\camera\camera_opencv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\camera
      copying kivy\core\camera\camera_picamera.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\camera
      copying kivy\core\camera\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\camera
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
      copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_android.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
      copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_dbusklipper.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
      copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_dummy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
      copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_gtk3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
      copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_nspaste.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
      copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_pygame.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
      copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_sdl2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
      copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_winctypes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
      copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_xclip.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
      copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_xsel.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
      copying kivy\core\clipboard\_clipboard_ext.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
      copying kivy\core\clipboard\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\image
      copying kivy\core\image\img_dds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\image
      copying kivy\core\image\img_ffpyplayer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\image
      copying kivy\core\image\img_gif.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\image
      copying kivy\core\image\img_pil.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\image
      copying kivy\core\image\img_pygame.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\image
      copying kivy\core\image\img_sdl2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\image
      copying kivy\core\image\img_tex.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\image
      copying kivy\core\image\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\image
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\gl
      copying kivy\core\gl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\gl
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\spelling
      copying kivy\core\spelling\spelling_enchant.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\spelling
      copying kivy\core\spelling\spelling_osxappkit.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\spelling
      copying kivy\core\spelling\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\spelling
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\text
      copying kivy\core\text\markup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\text
      copying kivy\core\text\text_pango.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\text
      copying kivy\core\text\text_pil.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\text
      copying kivy\core\text\text_pygame.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\text
      copying kivy\core\text\text_sdl2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\text
      copying kivy\core\text\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\text
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\video
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\input\providers
      copying kivy\input\providers\androidjoystick.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\input\providers
      copying kivy\input\providers\hidinput.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\input\providers
      copying kivy\input\providers\leapfinger.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\input\providers
      copying kivy\input\providers\linuxwacom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\input\providers
      copying kivy\input\providers\mactouch.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\input\providers
      copying kivy\input\providers\mouse.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\input\providers
      copying kivy\input\providers\mtdev.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\input\providers

      copying kivy\input\providers\probesysfs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\input\providers
      copying kivy\input\providers\tuio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\input\providers
      copying kivy\input\providers\wm_common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\input\providers
      copying kivy\input\providers\wm_pen.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\input\providers
      copying kivy\input\providers\wm_touch.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\input\providers
      copying kivy\input\providers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\input\providers
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\lang
      copying kivy\lang\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\lang
      copying kivy\lang\parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\lang
      copying kivy\lang\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\lang
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\lib
      copying kivy\lib\ddsfile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\lib
      copying kivy\lib\mtdev.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\lib
      copying kivy\lib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\lib
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\lib\gstplayer
      copying kivy\lib\gstplayer\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\lib\gstplayer
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\lib\vidcore_lite
      copying kivy\lib\vidcore_lite\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\lib\vidcore_lite
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\modules
      copying kivy\modules\console.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\modules
      copying kivy\modules\cursor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\modules
      copying kivy\modules\inspector.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\modules
      copying kivy\modules\joycursor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\modules
      copying kivy\modules\keybinding.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\modules
      copying kivy\modules\monitor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\modules
      copying kivy\modules\recorder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\modules
      copying kivy\modules\screen.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\modules
      copying kivy\modules\showborder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\modules
      copying kivy\modules\touchring.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\modules
      copying kivy\modules\webdebugger.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\modules
      copying kivy\modules\_webdebugger.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\modules
      copying kivy\modules\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\modules
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\network
        copying kivy\tests\test_uix_asyncimage.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
        copying kivy\tests\test_uix_boxlayout.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
        copying kivy\tests\test_uix_gridlayout.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
        copying kivy\tests\test_uix_layout.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
        copying kivy\tests\test_uix_relativelayout.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
        copying kivy\tests\test_uix_scrollview.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
        copying kivy\tests\test_uix_slider.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
        copying kivy\tests\test_uix_stacklayout.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
        copying kivy\tests\test_uix_textinput.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
```

...
..
            copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\vkeyboard_disabled_key_normal.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
            copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\vkeyboard_key_down.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
            copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\vkeyboard_key_normal.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
            running build_ext
            ----------------------------------------
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477: 'c:\users\michael\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7_3s7j11\kivy\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7_3s7j11\kivy\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-j5_4w5bq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\michael\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\kivy' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6563

Comment: No, I checked it.

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments?

Comment: @Michaelan The error message says _Check the logs for full command output_, is that what you shared here?

Answer (score 3):

Check GitHub once more.

> We are not likely to release a 1.11.1 version for 3.8 to pypi. However, you can install kivy master using `pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/`

And you just wrote `pip install kivy[base]`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the installation problem is that kivy doesn't compatible to python 3.8.X. So you need python 2.7.X to 3.7.X to run kivy. And then all the general installation process like for windows, type the followings serially in the command prompt :

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle
python -m pip install pygame (Note: Optional)
python -m pip install kivy
python -m pip install kivy_examples (Note: Optional)
```

And everything will work just fine.
Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

for `python 3.8.x`, use this command below

```
pip install Kivy==2.0.0rc4
```